# What does the delayMillis parameter actually stand for in Handler.postDelayed() method?

Tags: android, android-handler

The documentation for **Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)** says -

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses.
>
> **r**     The Runnable that will be executed.
>   **delayMillis**   The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.

**NOTE**: The last word is *Executed*, and **not** *Added to Message Queue*. The Runnable is added to the end of message queue instantly. Which means, the delay in executing this Runnable will be equal to the time taken to execute the messages / runnables in front of this Runnable in the message queue. How is it guaranteed that both the times are equal ? Am I missing something?

For example, assume the MessageQueue currently contains A,B,C which takes 1, 1.6, 2 seconds respectively, and handler.postDelayed(R, 4000) now appends R at the end of MessageQueue. A,B,C will be completed in 4.6 seconds, but R is scheduled to run after 4 seconds. How is this possible? What if the delay was more than 4.6 seconds?

[URL - Android Reference page for Handler postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Comment: Basically it will be run after at least `delayMillis` milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an exact delay. Think of the delay as "not earlier than". After the delay the runnable is eligible for execution but it's only run when the message queue has processed any prior messages.

Moral: Make sure you process your messages/runnables without blocking the thread for extensive amounts of time.